# Why is query show() not working in this sample?

Tags: jquery

We use the same setup (source: https://gist.github.com/johnchambers/5a6e67f2d7d39031af17) on different pages and normally it is working fine but this time the cookie_directive_container is not showing at all on this page: [haarem.ch](https://www.haar-em.ch/)

We have the Script and Cookie Banner in the file cookie_accept.asp and include the file in our index.asp. I find the code in the source code of the live page so there's no problem with the include. Where is the problem?

```js
(function($) {

  checkCookie_eu();

  function checkCookie_eu() {

    var consent = getCookie_eu("cookies_consent");

    if (consent == null || consent == "" || consent == undefined) {
      // show notification bar
      $('#cookie_directive_container').show();
    }

  }

  function setCookie_eu(c_name, value, exdays) {

    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value + "; path=/";
    $('#cookie_directive_container').hide('slow');
  }


  function getCookie_eu(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
      x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
      x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
      if (x == c_name) {
        return unescape(y);
      }
    }
  }

  $("#cookie_accept a.pull-right").click(function() {
    setCookie_eu("cookies_consent", 1, 30);
  });


}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cookie_directive_container" style="display:none;" role="alert">
  <div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container" id="cookie_accept">
      <a href="#" class="btn pull-right">Einverstanden</a>
      <p class="credit">
        Wir verwenden Cookies, um die Nutzung der Webseite zu verbessern. Bei weiterer Nutzung der Webseite akzeptieren Sie unsere <a href="index.asp?inc=datenschutzerklaerung.asp" target="_blank">Datenschutzerkl&auml;rung</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where is the problem that the cookie banner is not showing?

Comment: Not too sure use console.log("here") and google chrome to display some console logs see if you js is executing. Your cookies seem to be null but do an output of getCookie_eu("cookies_consent"); anyway console.log(consent) should assist in  checkCookie_eu

Comment: Have you tested what `consent` is returning as? Also, as a side note, instead of `consent == null || consent == "" || consent == undefined` you can use `!consent`: all three of the conditions in your OR are "falsy", which is included in `!consent`.

Comment: You're not returning anything from `getCookie_eu`

Comment: console.log(consent) returns "undefined". So it should go into the if clause and there active the container with the show.

The exact same code is working on all other pages. just on this one not. this is an oder one. can there be a problem that not the correct lib is activated?

Comment: No help in this case for me?